# How to use whereIn() when column names don't match?

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to use whereIn() to find records who have 'prov' that can be found in this array;

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
"id" => 1
"contest_id" => 1
"contest_zone_id" => 1
"province" => "ON"
"created_at" => "2018-06-20 13:37:45"
"updated_at" => "2018-06-20 13:37:45"
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
"id" => 2
"contest_id" => 1
"contest_zone_id" => 1
"province" => "SK"
"created_at" => "2018-06-20 13:37:45"
"updated_at" => "2018-06-20 13:37:45"
  ]
  2 => array:6 [▼
"id" => 3
"contest_id" => 1
"contest_zone_id" => 1
"province" => "NB"
"created_at" => "2018-06-20 13:37:45"
"updated_at" => "2018-06-20 13:37:45"
]
]
```

So I can do this;

```
->whereIn('prov', $provinces)
```

However, in my 2 tables 'prov' and 'province' aren't the same so it's not working.  Is there a way to explicitly declare which columns I want to compare?

Thanks!

**UPDATE WITH FIX**

Array needs to be pared down to just the field you are looking to match.

Comment: Probably need to show the full query; you could use `->whereIn()` then `->orWhereIn()`, but this is likely to fail with a `column not found` error. I'm not sure how you're trying to query two different tables in this manner.

Comment: Ah fudge.  As is generally the case, if you try to explain the issue through a SO question, you'll uncover your issue.  My array was a collection.  I needed to pare down to the field I was trying to match.  My mistake.  Thanks for reply.

Comment: Ah yeah, that can happen. If it helps, `Collection`s have a `filter()` function, so something like  `->filter(function($record) use($provinces){ return in_array($record->prov, $provinces) || in_array($record->province, $provinces) });` Oh and feel free to self-answer; might help someone else in the future.